# Formula Field Image is Not Visible in Community Pages

Tags: community, formula, formula-field

Following this guide https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eNzdAAE&title=image-formula-field-not-displaying-in-napili-community-template

I have uploaded my image as an asset in the Site.com Studio and am attemtping to use a formula field to display the image. My formula is as follows

```
IMAGE("/https://my-community.cs84.force.com/s/32-goals.jpg", "goal", 20, 20)
```

But in the Community the field is displayed as so '#Error!'. I have tried searching on this site but so far none of the suggestions work, Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to see the image from formula field when viewed on the object's record detail page?

Comment: No it also shows the same error.